# instance methods invokation in python

Tags: python, methods, instance

**does objects have its methods or invoke them from superclass in python?**
for example:

```
class tst():
    def __init__(self,name,family):
        self.name=name
        self.family=family
        
    def fun(self,a,b):
        print(a+b)


newtst=tst("myname","my family")

tst.fun(newtst,3,5)
newtst.fun(3,5)
```

in the code above does `newtst` object invoke `fun` function from `tst` class or it has own method and run it directly
and if the latter is true why we need to self parameter in definition class's functions
and in know that `id(newtst.fun)` is different from `id(tst.fun)` but i think that differences is because of creating new method's object in memory.

Comment: `newtst` is an instance of `tst`. And you don't have to pass the instance object to `fun` method as it's first argument.

Comment: no it's  true. try it yourself

Answer (score 1):

Instance methods are implemented as [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods) in python.
This implies, the separate instances are not keeping individual copies of method, but getting the same attribute of a different instances may produce individual results for each of them.

Despite we have the same function object beyond the attributes of all the instances we have, it still doesn't means that

```
id(tst.fun) == id(newtst.fun)
```

because method descriptor gives us different things when calling on a class and a class instance.

For a class we'll get an **unbound** method from `tst`, but for `newtst` it will be **bound** to an instance.